# running hadoop wordcount program

Tags: hadoop, word-count

I am learning hadoop by following [michael-noll](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster) tutorials. When I tried to run wordcount example by running `hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar wordcount tmp/Files tmp/Output` I am getting following error:

> 13/11/10 18:09:42 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54311. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
>
> .
>   .
>
> 13/11/10 18:09:51 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54311 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>   java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54311 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at
>
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1142)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1118)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.createProxy(JobClient.java:559)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:498)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.(JobClient.java:479)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:563)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:561)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:549)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:82)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
>   caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:708)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:511)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:481)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:457)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:583)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2200(Client.java:205)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1249)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1093)
>   ... 33 more

Addendum

I just re-ran the commands like this `bin/stop-all.sh`, `bin/start-all.sh`, `hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar wordcount tmp/Files tmp/Output`. But now am getting following error :

> 13/11/10 20:52:12 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SafeModeException: JobTracker is in safe mode
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.checkSafeMode(JobTracker.java:5188)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getStagingAreaDir(JobTracker.java:3677)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SafeModeException: JobTracker is in safe mode
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.checkSafeMode(JobTracker.java:5188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getStagingAreaDir(JobTracker.java:3677)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Plz help

Comment: you have to start hadoop cluster before running map reduce program

Comment: i had executed this command before running it >bin/start-all.sh

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually turn off safe mode:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode off
```

or

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Then rerun your job.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your JobTracker is in safemode, and not the nameNode. Use the following command to make sure JT is not in safemode :

```
bin/hadoop mradmin -safemode leave
```

You can anytime use the below shown commands to check if your NN and JT are out of the safemode or not ;

```
bin/hadoop mradmin -safemode get

bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode get
```

Also, please make sure that you are using correct user to start the daemons.

[image]

@Praveen Sripati : Please see the second last option.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you verify this before downvoting the answer.

Comment: mradmin doesnot support the safemode option.

Comment: On what grounds did you conclude that?